# Trello - prioritize cards between boards

Tags: trello

You can obviously prioritize cards within boards, but is there a way to prioritize cards between boards?  For example, if I have 10 boards and 35 cards, instead of having my developer check each board for what is the next priority, is there a way to create a summary prioritization of the 35 cards into one place?

Answer (score 3):

Boards are usually independent of each other, though you can use the Card View to get an overview of all cards across all boards, there are 2 requirements for this to work:

1. The user must be subscribed to each card (required for the card to appear).
2. Each card must have a due date (required for the card to be usefully sorted).

To get to the Card View, go to your profile icon and click it to drop down the menu, choose "Cards" and in the following page select "Sort by due date".

[image: Trello Profile Menu]